# Electron: dialog.showMessageBox() not working with a parent window (modal failed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm learning Electron and trying very basic things... without success.

Whatever the technique I use to make a dialog box modal, it fails. Either the dialog box is not modal, or the dialog box is empty (...and still not modal).

```
const {BrowserWindow, dialog} = require('electron')

dialog.showMessageBoxSync(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), {message: "FooBar"});
// Not modal: BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow() returns null.

dialog.showMessageBoxSync(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0], {message: "FooBar"});
// Not modal: BrowserWindow.getAllWindows() returns an empty array.

dialog.showMessageBoxSync(parentWindow, {message: "FooBar"});
// "parentWindow" comes from the "click" handler of the menu item launching the message box: it is not null.
// Error: the message box is not modal, and does not display "FooBar" (i.e. it is empty).
```

This code is called from the main process, and no error is displayed in the terminal or the development tools. The outcome is the same if I use `dialog.showMessageBox()` instead of `showMessageBoxSync()`.

Electron: v9.0.5 on Windows 10 (x64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the bug was that my main window is a subclass of `BrowserWindow`. Electron does not allow to subclass native classes. See issues:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8898
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10019
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15456

Too bad that the official documentation does still not mention this important restriction.

Answer (score 0):

`dialog.showMessageBoxSync` accepts 2 arguments in which first one is optional. so even if it is null or undefined it'll work without it.
so every dialog module method works only works after app is ready.

so make sure you are calling it after app is ready.

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  // create window call

  // your code

  dialog.showMessageBoxSync(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), {message: "FooBar"});

  dialog.showMessageBoxSync(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0], {message: "FooBar"});
})
```

or any other ready listen way will work. like `app.whenReady()`.

Comment: This does not answer my problem :( The code is called by a menu item from a main window created after the "ready" event is emitted. So I don't understand why `BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()` returns an empty array, and why passing the `window` argument from the `click` handler of the menu item make the message box display empty, whereas it should display "FooBar".

Comment: i did checked before answering it. worked perfectly for these 2 function calls.

Comment: It works because `BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()` returns an instance of `BrowserWindow`... which was not my case. See my own answer to this issue.